# Block of code is not touched

Tags: java, list, file, null

I'm building a small application in Java, small game mechanics but nothing serious. I have a class which purpose is to fetch data from a file. But when I declare the two classes to read from it the program justs ignore everything and continues. As a result, when I try to access the respective lists it gives me null pointer exception. Code of the method that fetches data below:

```
public void getData(int l, player tmp, level le) {
        String[] dataPlayer;
        String[] dataLevel;

        try {
            //FileReader f = new FileReader(this.levelPath.concat(Integer.toString(l)));
            File f = new File(this.levelPath.concat(Integer.toString(l)));
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            System.out.println("Reached");

            boolean eof = false;
            while (!eof) {
                String b = buff.readLine();

                if (b == null)
                    eof = true;
                else {
                    if (b.contains("player")) {
                        dataPlayer = b.split("-");
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataPlayer.length; i++) {
                            if (i == 0)
                                continue;

                            items it = new items(dataPlayer[i]);
                            tmp.setInventory1(it);
                        }
                    }else if (b.contains("level")) {
                        dataLevel = b.split("-");
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataLevel.length; i++) {
                            if (i == 0)
                                continue;

                            items it = new items(dataLevel[i]);
                            le.setSpecific(it);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException i) {
            i.getMessage();
        }


    }
```

**File contents of the file "levelData1":**

```
player-hat
player-flashlight
level-flower
level-rock
player-adz
```

**The problem with this particular problem was the path, it needed the absolute like that /home/toomlg4u/IdeaProjects/javaProject/src/Data/levelData.**

Comment: I'd guess that `buff` is null, your file name calculation seems a little over complicated. Or the file is empty.

Comment: @NiVeR I need that because I have 3 files for 3 levels, and an attribute called levelpath which equals "levelData" so I concat the argument l which is a number that the user gives e.g 1,2,3 (levels) so I open the appropriate file for reading. But really puzzled with this...

Comment: have you tried debugging? you can stop in one of the loops where items are created to check if it gets inside.

Comment: I have tried that, it never gets below the bufferedReader class

Comment: Then you must have some exception, are you seeing something?

Comment: I should add because I don't see anything. I'll try that.

Comment: 1) `}catch (IOException i) {
            i.getMessage();
        }` Not sure what you ***expect*** to happen in this code, but nothing useful **will** happen. Change it to `}catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }` 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson That did help me, and proved that the file doesn't exist according to the program atleast.

Comment: Cool. Yes, stack traces can be very informative. Now perhaps change `File f = new File(this.levelPath.concat(Integer.toString(l)));` to `File f = new File(this.levelPath.concat(Integer.toString(l))); System.out.println(f.getAbsolutPath());` Check that it points where you **think** it points.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a lot of things inside that try/catch that may not throw an IOException. If you get any other exception, it's not going to be caught. Depending on what other exception handling you have in place, that may cause weird behavior. For debugging, you could catch all exceptions, and see if you're getting something else.

Comment: I'm convinced now that the problem is the BufferReader object after that the code is not touched.

Comment: Ok, so now convince me of that.  =]  What i always recommend in this situation is to reduce the code down to the simplest it can possibly be, including cutting out everything AFTER when you think the error might occur. For your example, since there's code that isn't being reached, get rid of that code (comment it out, create a new project with just the code you know works, whatever. Don't make any nested function calls, one operation per line. Set a breakpoint before where you think the error occurs, and step thru the code, inspecting everything as you go. This should point you at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remain to your loop code then you can refactor your code to look like this one:

```
public void getData(int l, player tmp, level le) {
    try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(this.levelPath + l)))) {
        String b;
        while ((b = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            if (b.contains("player")) {
                String[] dataPlayer = b.split("-");
                items it = new items(dataPlayer[1]); //because you know that you will have an array with only 2 elements
                tmp.setInventory1(it);
            }else if (b.contains("level")) {
                String[] dataLevel = b.split("-");
                items it = new items(dataLevel[1]); //because you know that you will have an array with only 2 elements
                le.setSpecific(it);
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It is a little bit better than that you have, easier to debug and to read. I advice you to read about [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

As a rule of thumb, each time when you open a stream you have to close it. When you don't open it yourself then don't close it.

Comment: It will not work, for some reason in my original code and yours now, it won't find the file. I even tried absolute path.

Comment: how do you start the project?

Comment: I changed again the path and it worked. BUT, stopped again in the line I pass the new item (it) to my tmp.setInventory1. With null pointer exception.

Comment: You can use this line for example: `try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/game.txt"))))` and in this case the `game.txt` file should be placed in the class path. If you still have the NPE then please post the content of the `player` class so that I can see the content of the `setInventory1` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look like a decent program in Java:

```
private Stream<Items> asStreamOfItems(String line){
    return Stream.of(line.split("-")).skip(1).map(Items::new);
}

public void parseFile(String pathToTheFile) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pathToTheFile));
    List<Items> players = lines.stream().filter(line -> line.contains("player")).flatMap(this::asStreamOfItems).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Items> levels = lines.stream().filter(line -> line.contains("level")).flatMap(this::asStreamOfItems).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ........
}
```

In this case all your weird errors will vanish.

---

After you edited the post I saw your file content. In this case the code should look like this one:

```
class Items {
    private final String name;

    public Items(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Items parse(String line) {
        return new Items(line.split("-")[1]);
    }

}

public void parseFile(String pathToTheFile) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pathToTheFile));
    List<Items> players = lines.stream().filter(line -> line.contains("player")).map(Items::parse).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Items> levels = lines.stream().filter(line -> line.contains("level")).map(Items::parse).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ..............
}
```

Btw, you broke a lot of Java and general programming rules like:

1. using continue is a bad practice. It should be used only in extreme cases because it makes the code difficult to read.
2. the class name in Java should be in the CamelCase notation
3. one method should have only one responsibility
4. DON'T mutate the object inside of a method (example: `tmp.setInventory1(it);`) very very very bad practice
5. when you work with streams use try with resource or try/catch/finally to close your stream after you finish the reading.
6. Before jumping to write code explore the JAVA IO SDK to look for better methods to read from files

Comment: "This is how a real house is done. So demolish yours because is old and ugly, who cares if you have the resources."

Comment: I'm new to Java, and this method is the method that my teacher's book had. Ofcourse not the best but I had to start at something. BTW your code may work but I have a lot in order to get to this level, so I will for the moment stick to the basics.

Comment: Don't worry buddy, I will try my best. I would like to see you though when you are in a company and face your first legacy project, to comment that the code sucks and tell the authors how should've written it.